# what is "chat" in this presencechannel and "chat" in echo.join?

Tags: vue.js, pusher

Im so new in pusher and vue js

And i got this code

what is"chat" in there?

```
class ChatEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
   public function __construct(Chat $chat)
{
    $this->chat = $chat;
}

public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PresenceChannel('chat'); // what's chat in here? create channel pucher? construct 
                                            function? 
}}


      
 Echo.join('chat')   // what is chat in here too?  is this chat from the broadcaston func above?
.here(user => {

  user = user.concat(this.users_list)
```

sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

See:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#the-shouldbroadcast-interface

In this case, `chat` is the name of the channel. The name is something you can choose yourself, in this case it's a very generic name. But you could make it more specific, e.g. `chat.n`, where `n` is an identifier you can later use to authenticate people to the specific channel.